# I'm getting an error message I get when attempting to Install CL-PNG in Emacs using Quicklisp

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, quicklisp

I hope the answers I get can help others in installing Lisp Packages in general. I installed libpng with the setup.exe (at this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libpng/1.2.37/libpng-1.2.37-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=iweb)...I didn't do it manually....I'm using Sbcl for my Lisp Implemaenation.   I tried to run  (ql:quickload "png")in Emacs but I keep getting this error Message when I do:

> External process exited with code 1.
>   Command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" "-m32" "-I/opt/local/include" "-I/Program Files (x86)/Steel Bank Common Lisp/1.1.4/site/cffi/" "-o" "D:\Users\W\AppData\Local\common-lisp\cache\sbcl-1.1.4-win-x86\D\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\cl-png-0.6\grovel.exe" "D:\Users\W\AppData\Local\common-lisp\cache\sbcl-1.1.4-win-x86\D\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\cl-png-0.6\grovel.c"
>   Output was:

[Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Other things I tried:

I took all the dll files from the D:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32 (folder where libpng is installed),  all the dll files pertaining to libpng that is, and copied them to my SBCL\1.14 folder as is common practice for dll files so SBCL can access them. but still got above error:

I'm in Windows 8 - I added D:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\ (folder where libpng is installed) to my path enviornment variable  because libpng setup.exe didn't seem to add an enviornment variable , but no luck still get same\above error in Emacs ....Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you have gcc installed at `C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe`?

Comment: @Vsevolod Dyomkin to Make sure mingw is installed right i precicely reinstalled with the "Graphical User Interface Installer" instructions at this link:http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started I installed it to D:\MinGW (D: is my root drive in my primary Windows 8 OS)this time last time I installed it to C:MinGW(my root drive in my Backup Windows 7 OS) because thatsa what I thought it wanted. I would really like to keep it on D: but when I run (ql:quickload "png") in emacs i get " Couldn't execute "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe": No error" ...cont. on next comment

Comment: cont. from previous comment....i added "D:\MinGW\bin;D:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" without quotes to my "User"(top one) environment variables.  pls help me make this work with Mingw on D: drive if possible...Thanks Vsevolod Dyomkin for your speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

You probably found the solution within the past 5 months, but [this blog shows the answer](http://wnetai.wordpress.com/how-to-install-gsll_the-gnu-scientific-library-for-lisp-on-windows-7-and-windows-8/error-message-you-may-get-when-installing-gsll-and-their-solutions/) and is a nice reference for future readers, I think.

Citing (and shortening) the original author:

you have to copy the files ffi.h and ffitarget.h and the gsl folder from the include folder of your libffi installation and paste them into the include folder of your MinGW installation.